# WebAuthenticationBroker in Win10 Tablet Mode

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

We're using the WebAuthenticationBroker to connect to OAuth providers such as Facebook, Flickr and Instagram in our Windows 10 UAP app. When the OS is in tablet mode, the header bar of the WebAuthenticationBroker dialog is hidden, leaving the user no way to cancel out of the dialog. Is there any way to force the header of the control to remain visible when in tablet mode? Or should the onus be on the Oauth provider to render a control on their authorization page that redirects to the callback URL provided when the broker was invoked?

UPDATE:
Microsoft has acknowledged this issue and have fixed this in the current Insider Fast Preview Build. They've added a back button to the WebAuthenticationBroker in tablet mode similar to the control on the desktop mode's interface. This will allow a user to dismiss the dialog if they choose not to authenticate or wish to cancel out of an error state.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer as accepted if you didn't find a way to do it.. making other devs life easier :)

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't work in our case. We want the security of the WebAuthenticationBroker. I reported the issue to MS, and Rob Caplan acknowledged it. It will be addressed in a future release of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

By default, tablet mode is like the Mobile view, no title bar for dialogs (most cases).. and you can't customize the auth broker view :(

As a workaround, you can manually do it by a webview control if you really have to customize it.